# Change the language of camera buttons on iOS?

Tags: ios, flutter, imagepicker

Is it possible to change the language of camera buttons by using image_picker package? when I open the camera I want to show "cancel" button and "photo" text in other language exactly such as the device language. the text appears always in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a key to your Info.plist file

```
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>tr</string>
```

For example this makes the button languages turkish